# No account picker when using GoogleSignInClient

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-signin, google-play-games

I've made a lot of investigation about this problem, it's bugging me for like three days in a row now and I think I need a fresh look from the side.

*You can click image to view a full-size version of it.*

My problem is - I want the Google Play Games account picker to appear everytime I signing in using [GoogleSignInClient](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). But now, when I'm signing in with [Google Play Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin) scope, the consent window shows up:
[image]

The account picker shows up only if I prees **Deny**:
[image]

If I press **Allow** it caches my profile somethere and next time I press **Sign In** it dosen't ask me anything, just silently signing me in with my *default account*. Even if I call **GoogleSignInClient.signOut()** before that. The only thing that makes the consent window to appear again is to call **GoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()** before signing in.

I think the reason behind this is this checkbox in the Google Games account settings:
[image]

BUT, if I run any Google sample from here https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples (ButtonClicker for instance) the account picker shows up everytime I press **Sign In** button after pressing **Sign Out**. I don't know what is the difference between my test sample app and those samples. I've even tried to use lower versions of Google Services and Android SDK.

It's very simple to reproduce - just make an basic Android app with empty activity and make there a two buttons: **Sign In** and **Sign Out**. Of course you need Goole Play Application configured to test this. The code goes here https://gist.github.com/glcoder/c2783ad8c99063fc12250b9e32620751

**EDIT:** After some in depth analysis (mainly chpooing pieces off ButtonClicker from Google Samples) I've found what triggers account picker to show on the next sign in - this line of code, called right after successful sign in:

```
Games.getGamesClient(MainActivity.this, googleSignInAccount);
```

I think this is some strange behavior indeed.